# What's the best tether for keeping my stylus attached to my Tablet PC?

Tags: tablet, accessories

I have an HP Touchsmart tx2z, and the dinky little string lanyard that comes with the stylus for keeping it from getting lost by keeping it tethered to the computer doesn't cut it for me: it's too short to use the tablet in some orientations (such as when the screen is angled up from the body) and too long and easily tangled when the pen is stored. Can anybody suggest a replacement cord? Ideally, I'd want something long, that retracts when not in use, with a brush on the spool for when the screen gets dusty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something along the lines of a [keychain or ID badge retractor](http://www.idsuperstore.com/badge-reels-c-76.html)?

Comment: It's the kind of thing I'm looking for, but the trouble is fitting it through both of the little hole for the original lanyard- http://www.idsuperstore.com/lanyard-smart-reels-with-quick-lock-and-button-release-system-p-30759.html is the closest anything has come (I'm going to see if I can get an evaluation sample).

Answer (score 0):

We have the same tablet that we use with our Barcode Scanner, the 'string' was the first to go, quickly followed by the original and the spare stylus! In the end we used some BLACK ADHESIVE 25mm VELCRO (you'll find it on eBay and on big stationary suppliers)  We stick the "Plush" side of the Velcro on the top edge of the tablet while you are holding it in 'portrait' mode,  With another little square on the front bezel.  Then we stick the 'hook' side of the Velcro around the Stylus.  The Velcro holds on very tight, enough for the stylus to stay on even taking the tablet in and out of it's neoprene 'sock' case.

Also as a suggestion instead of using the 'crappy' HP stylus, you can 'upgrade' to a much more useful 'all-in-one'
do a google/ebay search for "4 in 1 Laser Pointer+Ball Pen+PDA Stylus Pen+LED Light"

[image]

Stick your Velcro on this thing and it's also an LED torch, a REAL pen and a Laser Pointer to scare the cat!

[image]

Comment: Well, my HP stylus has an active digitizer, and retracts into the case, which kind of beats all of the advantages of that method while neither ameliorate any of the original problems (that the stylus can be lost while not attached to the system).